# How do I unzip Gunzip and how do I parse the object into Json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I need to upload a profile picture to a profile. I need to get the ID so I upload the picture to the right profile. The respone from the API is a Gunzip object.

.then(resp => JSON.parse(resp)).then(data => {console.log(data.Gunzip.read(5)} )

I have tried this but got an error: (node:16100) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const userID = '12345'
const EXAMPLE_PUT_URL = `https://backend.example.com/api/users/${userID}`
const EXAMPLE_GET_URL = `https://backend.example.com/api/users/?limit=5`

const ACCESS_TOKEN = 'NWNmNmYyOWMzNTk5YTA3YjU3MGZkN2Y2OmV6UXo1TiZnXmVtWmJfKzRsOFJ5LWFMLShUUzFzbno7dDNpLV5KX0dOLFIwT1dkTFh1VFZWalE2LFNtKX4pV3U='

var fs = require('fs');

var contents = fs.readFileSync('images/profile1.jpg', 'utf8');

fetch(EXAMPLE_GET_URL, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      "Authorization": `Basic ${ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
      "Content-type": "application/json",
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Accept-Charset": "utf-8",
    }, 
  })
    .then(response => { 
          fetch(EXAMPLE_PUT_URL, {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
              "Authorization": `Basic ${ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
              "Content-type": "application/json",
              "Accept": "application/json",
              "Accept-Charset": "utf-8",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                  avatar:contents,
              })      
          })
          console.log(response)})
    ;
```

With this code I got the zipped object instead of the object, so I cannot see the ID I need.